# How to set a GirdView hight to wrap its contant - Flutter Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, gridview, flutter-web

In my flutter web app i have gird which shows the mentors it fetchesthe data from firebase firestore but the gidviews shows error

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
```

I have tired to wrap it in a expanded widget but did not work and when i wrap the gridview in sizedbox and set its height its works fine, but i want the height should be dynamic based on the items in the girdview.

The girdview is inside a listview.

This is my code

```
 StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('consultants')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: ProgressBar(loading: true),
                  );
                } else {
                  return GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                    children: snapshot.data.docs.map((documents) {
                      return ConsultantCard(
                        name: documents['name'],
                        profession: documents['profession'],
                        shortDesc: documents['shortDesc'],
                        countryCode: documents['countryCode'],
                        imageUrl: documents['imageUrl'],
                        rating: documents['rating'],
                        ratingsNum: documents['ratingsNum'],
                        fees: documents['fees'],
                        verified: documents['verified'],
                        popular: documents['popular'],
                        freeTrial: documents['freeTrial'],
                        languages: documents['languages'],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  );
                }
              }),
```

Comment: shrinkwrap : true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shrinkWrap: true`
This is what you need inside your gridView